# binary search on a list of dictionaries python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, binary-search

I am writing a binary search function in python to find to find elements in a list of dictionaries. I have the basic function working but I'm not sure how to go about adjusting it to search within a list of dictionaries. Below is an example of my data set(it is much much bigger) and the function I have developed. As said before the function works on a simple list of numbers but it doesn't on the data set. I want to search 'datetime' in this instance (e.g. all entries that occurred on 2nd of october 2019). I also want to be able to search for a range of values in the list of dictionaries ie. entries that have 'surface_temp' between 65 and 100.

```
fire1 = [{'latitude': '-37.591', 'longitude': '148.111', 'datetime':'2019-10-02T03:52:12', 'surface_temp':'57'}, {'latitude': '-31.231', 'longitude': '328.314', 'datetime':'2017-11-10T06:42:17', 'surface_temp':'60'}, 'latitude': '-23.594', 'longitude': '132.435', 'datetime':'2017-08-15T03:52:12', 'surface_temp':'23'}]

# Binary search function
def binary_search(data, key):
    
    matched_record = []
    
    bottom = 0
    top = len(data) -1
    found = False
    
    while(bottom <= top):
            middle = int((bottom + top)//2)
            if data[middle] == key : 
                matched_record.append((middle,key)) # position, key
                # looking for the duplicates in left side of the match
                for i in range(middle - 1, -1, -1):
                    if data[i] == key:
                        matched_record.append((i,key))
                    else:
                        break
                # looking for the duplicates in right side of the match
                for i in range(middle + 1, top):
                    if data[i] == key:
                        matched_record.append((i,key))
                    else:
                        break
                break
            else: 
                if key < data[middle]: 
                    top = middle -1
                else: 
                    bottom = middle +1
    
    return matched_record
```

When I try and run the code using the data set i get the following error:

```
binary_search(fire1, '2019-10-02')
```

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'dict'

any sort of help or guidance would be really appreciated and please let me know if I need to add any more information.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For your `TypeError`, replace `key < data[middle]` with `key < data[middle]['datetime'].split('T')[0]`. How can you compare a string with a dictionary ? That's what your error tells you too. And as far as binary search is concerned, sort the list based on the value you want to search for before you use your function. If you want to search based on the `surface_temp` use `fire1.sort(key = lambda row : row['surface_temp'])`.

Comment: thank you for your reply, how could i write it so that i could search a range of temperatures? say between 50 and 70?

Comment: I have tried this fix and while it fixes the error it returns an empty list, which it shouldn't as  there is definitely entries under the query

Comment: Include what you have tried. Instead of finding an element like we do in binary search, stop when the range intersects with the range you want to find.

Comment: I got it working in the end thank you.

Comment: However, when i try search by surface_temp i  do ```fire1.sort(key = lambda row: row['surface_temp'])``` and it comes up with the error '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'.... as when i use ```type(fire1[i]['surface_temp']) ``` the output is int

Comment: Bisection only works on ordered lists. Here, your list is ordered by date descending, so you can bisect and use date comparisons to find a single date or items from a range of dates, but you can't use this list to bisect on surface temperature as well. If you sort, that's fine if you're planning multiple searches but it's not clear that that's your use case. More context seems necessary here. How large is the list you're actually dealing with, how often will you search it, etc? In all likelihood, a simple list comprehension is a much simpler solution.

Comment: @BethanyHooper what problem do you face when you try this `fire1.sort(key = lambda row : row['surface_temp'])`. Can you include the inputs and the output you recieve in the question ?

Comment: @SurajSubramanian I got it working thank you.

Comment: Great, you can add your solution as the answer so any other person facing a similar problem can refer it !